What do i do with old google tag manager tags?
At my work they have a old setup i google tag manager from 5 years ago - almost all the tags are outdated and some of them are not working.
What is the best course of action? Delete them all and start from scratch or try to fix them?
I should metion that we are getting a new webisite, however there is no constent mode active and there is still a couple of months let before we get the new website.
I´m kinda of a new in GTM, so im not sure what is best thing to do?
I have not tried anything yet, but i have downloaded a backup of the tags and setup.
I feel like deleting them all and starting from scratch is the best thing to do, but is there something that would / could cause problems?

Well, if they are still being used e.g. for marketing campaigns those campaigns will fail if you delete the tags. Create your new configuration, in the old container create a new workspace in which you delete everything, import your ne confguration to that workspace and after testing publish it.  That way you don't need to change the gtm id in the code. But your question is not quite answerable, nobody from the outside can see if the old stuff can be safely deleted.

Here's a step-by-step plan to help you :
1/  Backup First: Always download a backup of your current GTM setup.
2/ Audit Existing Tags: Identify which tags are outdated, still relevant, or need further investigation.
3/ Categorize Tags:

Obsolete Tags: Delete these.
Useful Tags: Document and keep these for reference.
Investigate Tags: Evaluate and decide whether to keep or delete.

4/ Create a New Container: Start fresh with a new GTM container to avoid legacy issues.
5/ Implement Essential Tags: Recreate only the necessary and useful tags in the new container.
6/ Plan for the New Website: Coordinate with your web team to understand the new site’s needs and prepare accordingly.
7/ Test Thoroughly: Use GTM's Preview Mode to ensure all tags fire correctly before publishing.
8/ Monitor and Adjust: Continuously monitor the new setup and make adjustments as needed.
Good luck!

A really late, thank you! :)
